# Memcache Unknown error (0)

Tags: php, linux, memcached

I'm randomly getting a flood of Memcache errors in my log file that look like this:

> PHP Warning:  Memcache::pconnect(): Can't connect to 127.0.0.1:11211, Unknown error (0)
>   PHP Warning:  Memcache::close(): No servers added to memcache connection

After the flood, everything seems fine. I can telnet to the server.
memcached start up settings are -m 200 and -c 4096.

Here is a sample 'stats':

> stats
> STAT pid 7431
> STAT uptime 507682
> STAT time
>   1396973622
> STAT version 1.4.15
> STAT libevent
>   1.4.13-stable
> STAT pointer_size 64
> STAT rusage_user 914.539968
> STAT rusage_system 2714.912270
> STAT curr_connections 6
> STAT total_connections 1000139
> STAT connection_structures
>   757
> STAT reserved_fds 20
> STAT cmd_get 98098231
> STAT cmd_set
>   606357
> STAT cmd_flush 0
> STAT cmd_touch 0
> STAT get_hits
>   97491874
> STAT get_misses 606357
> STAT delete_misses 185
> STAT
>   delete_hits 109
> STAT incr_misses 0
> STAT incr_hits 0
> STAT
>   decr_misses 0
> STAT decr_hits 0
> STAT cas_misses 0
> STAT
>   cas_hits 0
> STAT cas_badval 0
> STAT touch_hits 0
> STAT
>   touch_misses 0
> STAT auth_cmds 0
> STAT auth_errors 0
> STAT
>   bytes_read 6509263367
> STAT bytes_written 8760129521
> STAT
>   limit_maxbytes 209715200
> STAT accepting_conns 1
> STAT
>   listen_disabled_num 0
> STAT threads 4
> STAT conn_yields 0
> STAT
>   hash_power_level 16
> STAT hash_bytes 524288
> STAT
>   hash_is_expanding 0
> STAT bytes 1942744
> STAT curr_items
>   16104
> STAT total_items 519747
> STAT expired_unfetched
>   5154
> STAT evicted_unfetched 0
> STAT evictions 0
> STAT reclaimed
>   290295
> END